# Installing a single file package in conda/pip requires redundant import statement

Tags: python, pip, python-import, conda, python-packaging

I've created a python package that is posted to pypi.org. The package consists of a single .py file, which is the same name as the package.

After installing the package via pip (`pip install package_name`) in a conda or standard python environment I must use the following statement to import a function from this module:

```
from package_name.package_name import function_x
```

How can I reorganise my package or adjust my installation command so that I may use import statement

```
from package_name import function_x
```

which I have successfully used when I install via `python setup.py install`.

My setup.py is below

```
setup(
    name = "package_name",
    version = "...",
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['examples', 'docs', 'build', 'dist']),

)
```

Comment: You're apparently asking `setuptools` to build a package with your module in it, instead of just installing your module. If you're not doing this explicitly, it's probably because you're using `find_packages` to just search the whole source tree and find all the packages. If you only have a single file anyway, it's probably easier to just not use it than to make it find your module as a flat module.

Comment: The only other possibility I can think of is that you have a `package_name` directory with an `__init__.py` and a module file named `package_name.py`, and the `__init__.py` is trying to import and re-export everything from the module, but somehow you've got `setuptools` either ignoring the `__init__.py` or replacing it. But that seems less likely to be your issue.

Comment: Thank you @abarnert. It was because I was using packages instead of py_modules in my setup arguments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your setup arguments from using packages to using py_modules e.g.

```
setup(
    name = "package_name",
    version = "..",
    py_modules=['package_name'],
)
```

This is documented here https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/introduction.html#a-simple-example